# UPDATED: Android: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android, eclipse, logcat, android-logcat

UPDATE** so i did pretty much everything that was said below and still got this error(see new logcat file). Its different though so i dont know how to fix it.**
Ok so im a beginner so i really dont know whats going on. When i try to run this app in the emulator all it is "unfortunately this app has stopped." Ive search all the question similar to this but haven't been able to find an answer. btw this isnt a finished app or really even started, but i want to get it to run before i continue. Heres the log cat file thing.

```
    error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-19 06:09:04.579: D/AndroidRuntime(1006): Shutting down VM
08-19 06:09:04.599: W/dalvikvm(1006): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080001 type #0x12 is not valid
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2103)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:852)
    at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:107)
    at com.nickymilton.testbasebal3.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:22)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2476)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:393)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:747)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:2913)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Now heres the activty_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="@string/EnterHome"
            android:textColor="@color/White" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:ems="10" 
            android:hint="@string/home_team"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
            android:shadowColor="@color/ICSBlue" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/editText1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:text="@string/EnterAway"
            android:textColor="@color/White" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/away_team"
            android:shadowColor="@color/ICSBlue" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="115dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/editText2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="@string/Enter" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/button3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:text="@string/Skip" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Now the activity_display_message.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then here the mainActivity.java file

```
package com.nickymilton.testbasebal3;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.nickymilton.Testbasebal3.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

then the second activity DisplayMessageActivity.java

```
package com.nickymilton.testbasebal3;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);
    }

    }
```

And finally the mainfest file

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nickymilton.testbasebal3"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.nickymilton.testbasebal3.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

So there it is. Someone please help thanks!

Comment: Where is your activity_main xml file?

Comment: Please select one of the answers as an answer to your question. Luksprog or Alexander Lucas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed one thing, you've not declared the 'id' values correctly in some of your xml.

```
android:id="@id/button3"
```

should be

```
android:id="@+id/button3"
```

And like wise for your other id declarations.

You'll notice that in your stack trace it gives you the line number in your xml for the location of the error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.nickymilton.testbasebal3/com.nickymilton.testbasebal3.MainActivity}:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #54: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

This might be something else. But essentially you have badly formed xml.

**Error Two**

You need to look through the stack trace backwards to find the source of your error, you will then most likely find the solution yourself.

```
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080001 type #0x12 is not valid
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2103)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:852)
    at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:107)
    at com.nickymilton.testbasebal3.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:22)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2476)
```

From the top down you'll get to the line *MainActivity.oncreateOptionsMenu()*
Above that you'll see that its trying to inflate (your options menu xml), i.e. *loadXmlResourceParser()*

It doesn't go as far as giving you an xml line number but it does tell you you have an issue with an Resource id not being valid.

You'll need to post your options xml in your question if you want an answer. But i would see if you can work it out your self first. Try commenting out elements and putting them back in to see whats broken. I say this because theres only so much one Stack overflow question should answer.

Answer (score 4):

There are issues with your XML - you can tell from the line:

```
Binary XML file line #54: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

One thing I spotted is that when you declare an android:id attribute, it needs to have a + in it, like this:

```
android:id="@+id/location"
```

This is because you're *creating* an id, not just referring to a pre-existing one defined elsewhere (like you might be with a string, e.g "@string/hello" might be in the values folder).

Comment: +1 because you explained that you can have @id/blah if referring to existing ids declared with @+id/blah.

Comment: did that...now i got a new error(I think) I updated both the layout xml and logcat file above

Answer (score 1):

In the declaration for one of your `TextViews` you have :

```
android:textSize="@string/TextSizefifteen"
```

`textSize` should be a number or a dimension like:

```
android:textSize="@dimen/TextSizefifteen"
```

See what you have at `TextSizefifteen` and how you declared it(see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension).

For example:

```
<dimen name="TextSizefifteen">25dp</dimen>
```

Comment: I just deleted the text size property from both and just kept it at the defualt. But i am still getting an error, a different one (I think) i updated the layout xml and the logcat files above

Comment: @NickyMilton Do you have a menu file named `activity_main` in a folder named `menu`?If you don't require a menu simply delete the line `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);`

Comment: @NickyMilton In your `MainActivity` class in the method `onCreateOptionMenu`.

Comment: OMFG Thank you so much! Finally Worked!

Comment: The problem with multiple questions in one question. Why not mark Alexander Lucas' Answer as the answer to your original question.

Comment: @Emile Post the comment to the question so the user can actually see it. To be fair Alexander Lucas's answer like yours was only part of the response.

Comment: True, you deserve an answer tick as well. However i would say a closed question is better than none. Toss a coin perhaps.